# How do I make a reservation via IRCTC in indian railway now (Paytm fails)

Tags: trains, bookings, indian-railways, irctc

IRCTC accept payment via net banking or wallets like *Paytm, mobiqwik,etc.*

I booked a ticket from Chennai to Tanur ( Place doesn't matter).

Then in the payment screen, wallets are there and also net banking is there but I didn't enabled it with my bank yet. Also no direct credit/debit card option is there.

So, I choose paytm, paid cash and confirmed the reservation. But after sometime,
I got a message form paytm that **Ticket booking failed, cash is refunded. It may take upto 7 working days for your bank to accept refund**.

How to book now?

Comment: IRCTC has support for a variety of payment options *including* credit/debit cards. There may be a temporary glitch due to which credit/debit cards were unavailable. You should try again after some time.

Comment: credit/debit option is there and I clicked it. But it redirect to paytm and accept cards via paytm gateway (like paypal). No direct accpet. Only using paytm, we can pay it and it fails.

Comment: Sorry but I can see and use the following payment options in my account - "Debit card with PIN", "Payment Gateway/Credit Card". You can choose the options on the left hand side menu. Possibly you are using the first option "Multiple Payment Services" which has Credit/Debit cards/netbanking (Powered by PayTM) and it is failing

Answer (score 3):

IRCTC supports a wide variety of payment options like

- Debit cards
- Netbanking
- Credit Cards (Even international ones)
- Mobile wallets

You can choose your preferred method on the booking screen, like this

[image: netbanking usage]

Possibly, you are using the first option "Multiple Payment Services", which has the PayTM option which is causing you problems.

[image: PayTm option]

Simply chose a different payment method from left side menu. For example, using a debit card with PIN gives

[image: debit cards]

In case of problems, you can contact IRCTC by e-mail.

Comment: But normally we are using card with cvv and expiry, then verify OTP via sms

Comment: Also, as mentioned in question, netbanking is not suitable for me because, I contacted 2 times my bank already in last year because of forgot password. The procedure to recover password is difficult.

Comment: The "debit card with PIN" works like that. You can also choose the payment gateway option where you can choose other payment gateways.